# .com vs .cl domain

Tags: domains, international

My company has a `.cl` TLD for our Chilean website. I think it would be better for SEO purposes to have a bilingual site. I wanted to reach out to the masses to see if you think there is any benefit to having the site on two different domains based on geography.

Comment: "any benefit to..." - Do you have a target audience outside of Chile? Does your company do business outside of Chile?

Answer (score 5):

### Overview on ccTLDs

**ccTLDs** *(country code top level domains)* are the single strongest way to show search engines and users that site content is specifically targeted to a certain country or region — but, importantly, NOT specifically a certain language.

If your website uses a ccTLD, Google will assume that both the website and all of its content are specifically relevant to the country/region of the ccTLD and it should primarily appear on SERPs in that country/region.

**Moreover, ccTLDs target geographic areas (countries, regions). They do not target languages.**

What does this mean?

Making your `.cl` website multilingual *may* help it rank higher **in Chile** for certain queries - **mainly** (see below) in cases like this:

- A page on your website normally ranks...say 2nd page for the term "How to fix my keyboard".
- The user's browser language is English
- The pages/sites on the 1st page of the search results *only* offer their content in Spanish - since your site offers an English version, Google includes your result on page 1 instead of 2.

This is not to say that making your site multilingual *will not* help you *globally*. Of course it will help, but perhaps not to the extent that it *could* (at least in the short term) if it was a TLD.

Making a site on a ccTLD multilingual will absolutely open the door to global rankings, but it's going to require *a lot* of additional signals (primarily links) over time to see visible results.

So when I say *mainly in cases like this*, I mean that it's in situations like those outlined above that you'll observe a *majority* of the benefit.

---

### Approaches to Internationalization

I'll start with a disclaimer that there are many *right* ways to accomplish internationalization. These are two approaches *I* would take in this situation based on my experience and established best practices. They are equally good methods of internationalization, but different depending on your longer term goals.

**Multiple Domains: Additional ccTLDs for Additional Countries/Regions**

I'm assuming this is what you might mean when you say "different domains based on geography". If you just want to target users in Mexico and the US you could create `.mx` and `.us` versions.

- **Pros:** Clear geo-targeting, server location is irrelevant, it will be easy to keep sites separate
- **Cons:** Might get expensive, the ccTLD name you want might not be available, will requires more infrastructure, you'll need to build up the backlink profiles of each ccTLD separately.

**Single Domain: Redirect `example.cl` to a gTLD (Generic Top Level Domain)**

If your goal is to eventually target many different countries, I would recommend this.

How it would work:

- 301 Redirect `example.cl` to `example.com`
- From there, use `hreflang`to designate additional international versions of your site. You would want to choose between a subdomain method or a subdirectory method to indicate these versions - Ex:`us.example.com` vs `example.com/en-us/` [Learn more](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/localized-versions)
- If you go this route, be sure to fill out Google's International Targeting report.

Helpful links:

- [Google's International Targeting report](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6059209?visit_id=637660451921157560-3496788957&rd=1)
- [Managing multilingual versions of your site](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/managing-multi-regional-sites)

Here's a current [list of TLDs](https://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt)

Comment: "Making your `.cl` website multilingual _may_ help it rank higher **in Chile**" - **and globally**. A ccTLD does not _only_ target users in that country. As [Google's John Mueller states in the linked question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/32752/1243): "it's no problem to create a _global site_ on a ccTLD". The OP hasn't stated that they want to target another specific region. From the limited information in the question, it would seem to be "Chile" and "everyone else".

Comment: @MrWhite OP says *"based on geography"* I agree that could go one way or another, unless I've missed something my answer controls for both approaches _optimally_. I absolutely agree with John (amazing find btw) _it can_ be done; sure it's not a "problem", but in practice that's *very* hard...requiring *a lot* of effort. Why go against the grain if you don't have to? Multilingual will help for sure, notice I said _mainly in cases like_. Good call tho, I should specify because that's unclear. Need to touch up a couple headings too.